# Copy files from one folder to multiple other folders where these files originally came from. Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

Hi so I have a following problem

Suppose you have some Windows folder structure with different files (all files have different names but may have the same extension):

```
dirA
  subDirA
    file1.png
    file2.dds
  file3.jpeg
dirB
  subDirB
    subSubDirB
      file4.tiff
    some_txt.txt
  test.cfg
final.docx
```

And now you copy all the files recursively to some other directory:

```
file1.png
file2.dds
file3.jpeg
file4.tiff
some_txt.txt
test.cfg
final.docx
```

And now what I want to do is to copy all these files back to their original folders (note that the previous folders and files are still there, I just copied them) and overwrite previous files. In reality there is a lot of files so it is not an option to manipulate them by hand.

Is there some simple way to do this or I'd better write custom program/script to do this?

Comment: You have 4 options: (1) maintain the same directory structure in the target directory; (2) keep a log of the original copy and use this as a basis for the reverse copy; (3) as each file is copied, also create a link in a separate directory pointing back to its source; and (4) for each file in the target directory, find the file of the same name in the source directory and copy back to to this. Note that (1) can be done with standard commands, but the other options will require scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would usually prefer a batch solution for something like this:

```
@echo off

set "orig=C:\Original\Directory"
set "dir=C:\Some\Directory"

for /r "%orig%" %%A in (*) do (
    if exist "%dir%\%%~nxA" copy /y "%dir%\%%~nxA" "%%A"
)
```

The `orig` variable will be the top-folder you want to loop recursively through (i.e. `dirA` or `dirB` from your example block - or if they share a folder you can go as high as you want as long as you're confident about there not being duplicate names). The `dir` variable will be that folder you had previously copied all of the files to.

`for /r` loops through *all* files rooted in a directory (meaning `orig` and all of its subfolders); for each iteration it sets the full path and extension of the file as `%%A`, then within the loop we see if `%%~nxA` (the file reduced to its name and extension) exists in our `dir` location; if it does exist, we copy that file from `dir` over itself in the `orig` location. That's it. If you'd like to generate a log file to check I usually recommend using robocopy and have it output everything from the loop into a text file, which would look like this:

```
@echo off

set "orig=C:\Original\Directory"
set "dir=C:\Some\Directory"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%orig%" %%A in (*) do (
    set "path=%%~dpA"
    if exist "%dir%\%%~nxA" robocopy "%dir%" "!path:~0,-1!" "%%~nxA"
)>>"%dir%\Return Files.txt"
```

Only tricky difference there is to enable delayed expansion so you can clip the trailing `\` from the `%%~dpA`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is impossible: The files in their new location no longer have the information, where they came from. This implies, that there is no way for a script to know, where it should put every file.

If you do have an old directory listing, this could be easily don with some scripting language.

Comment: Sure, I mentioned that the old files and folders are there, otherwise, as you said, it would be impossible. Just asking if anyone faced this problem and has an elegant solution with decent performance

Comment: It's not impossible as you can find the original files ...

Answer (score 0):

If you guarantee that there is no by-name duplicates, then use something like

```
forfiles /P X:\originals_folder /S /C "cmd /c copy Y:\copies_folder\@file @path\@file /Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell solution, using a hashtable to lookup paths:

```
$originals = 'c:\originals'
$copies    = 'c:\copies'
$hash = @{}
gci $originals -recurse | %{
   $hash[$_.name] = $_.Fullname
}
gci $copies | %{copy-item $_ $hash[$_.Name] -force
```